# Load more attributes into existing eloquent model instance

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to load additional attributes into model instance without multiple queries or hackery? Let me explain:

```php
// I got a tiny model with only id loaded
$model = Model::first(['id']);
// Then some code runs
// Then I decide I'd need `name` and `status` attributes
$model->loadMoreAttributes(['name', 'status']);
// And now I can joyously use name and status without additional queries
$model->name;
$model->status;
```

Does Eloquent have something similar to my fictional `loadMoreAttributes` function?

Notice kindly that I'm not a novice and am very well aware of `Model::find($model->id)` and such. They're just too wordy.

Thanks for your attention in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extend the Eloquent model to have this `loadMoreAttributes` method like so:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class YourModel extends Model
{
    public function loadMoreAttributes(array $columns)
    {
        // LIMITATION: can only load other attributes if id field is set.
        if (is_null($this->id)) {
            return $this;
        }

        $newAttributes = self::where('id', $this->id)->first($columns);

        if (! is_null($newAttributes)) {
            $this->forceFill($newAttributes->toArray());
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

This way you can do this on your model:

```
$model = YourModel::first(['id']);
$model->loadMoreAttributes(['name', 'status']);
```

**LIMITATION**

However there's a limitation to this hack. You may only call `loadMoreAttributes()` method if the unique `id` of your model instance is already fetched.

Hope this help!